# How to overload function for different iterator value_types in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement a template function in C++ 11 which takes a pair of iterators. The implementation should do some special processing if a pair of iterators is passed whose value type is an `std::pair` of arbitrary types. I tried to come up with the following definitions:

```
// arbitrary value types
template<typename Iter>
void process(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << "\n";
    }
}

// std::pair value types
template<typename Iter, typename First, typename Second,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type, std::pair<First,Second>
            >::value
        >::type* = 0>
void process(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
        std::cout << (*iter).first << " " << (*iter).second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Using the following example code:

```
std::vector<int> int_vec{{1,2,3,4}};
process(int_vec.begin(), int_vec.end());
```

correctly calls the first definition of the function `process`. However

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>> pair_vec{
    {std::make_pair(1, "First"), std::make_pair(2, "Second")}};
process(pair_vec.begin(), pair_vec.end());
```

also calls the first definition and results in the error message (using Clang):

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::__1::pair<int, std::__1::basic_string<char> >')
```

Why doesn't the compiler pick up the second definition in that case? How do I need to change the overloaded function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the template arguments `First` and `Second` can't be deduced from `Iter`, which is the only argument subject to template argument deduction, at the point at which you require them in the function signature.

You can, however, use `Iter` to deduce `First` and `Second` using a helper class (in the below example `IsPair`), and use template specialization there to select between two options.

**Example:**

```
template<typename T>
struct IsPair
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename First, typename Second>
struct IsPair<std::pair<First, Second>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

// arbitrary value types
template<typename Iter>
void process(Iter begin, Iter end, 
             typename std::enable_if<
                !IsPair<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>::value
             >::type* = 0)
{
    for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) 
    {
        std::cout << *iter << "\n";
    }
}

// std::pair value types
template<typename Iter>
void process(Iter begin, Iter end, 
             typename std::enable_if<
                 IsPair<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>::value
             >::type* = 0) 
{
    for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) 
    {
        std::cout << (*iter).first << " " << (*iter).second << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Working example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d0022c9977dd1cc)

Answer (score 3):

In your attempt to use `enable_if`, you're introducing two template parameters that are non-deduced contexts. There's no way for the compiler to determine what `First` and `Second` are, so that overload is always removed from the overload set. It's never considered.

I'd suggest sidestepping SFINAE entirely. If what you're doing simply involves performing some actual for every element the range, just use function overloads:

```
template <class T>
void process_impl(T const& elem) {
    // generic case
    std::cout << elem << '\n';
}

template <class T, class U>
void process_impl(std::pair<T, U> const& elem) {
    // overload for pair
    std::cout << elem.first << ' ' << elem.second << '\n';
}

template <class Iter>
void process(Iter first, Iter last) {
    // if C++14
    std::for_each(first, last, [](auto&& elem){ process_impl(elem); });

    // if C++11
    using E = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::reference;
    std::for_each(first, last, [](E elem) { process_impl(elem); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use tag dispatching e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <class> struct tag { };

template <class Iter, class T>
void process_impl(Iter begin, Iter end, tag<T>) {
   for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
       std::cout << *iter << "\n";
   }
}

template <class Iter, class First, class Second>
void process_impl(Iter begin, Iter end, tag<std::pair<First, Second>>) {
   for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
       std::cout << (*iter).first << " " << (*iter).second << "\n";
   }
}

template <class Iter>
void process(Iter begin, Iter end) {
   process_impl(begin, end, tag<typename Iter::value_type>{});
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int> int_vec{{1,2,3,4}};
   process(int_vec.begin(), int_vec.end());
   std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>> pair_vec{{std::make_pair(1, "First"), std::make_pair(2, "Second")}};
   process(pair_vec.begin(), pair_vec.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second specialization is never called because the compiler is never able to deduce the `First` and `Second` template type arguments. What you need instead is a trait that checks wether a given type is a specialization of `std::pair`. Here is what you could do:

```
template <template <typename ...> class Ref, typename T>
struct is_template_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename ...> class Ref, typename ... Args>
struct is_template_specialization<Ref, Ref<Args...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
using is_pair = is_template_specialization<std::pair, T>;
```

Now with such a trait, your SFINAE condition becomes:

```
// std::pair value types
template<typename Iter,
    typename std::enable_if<
        is_pair<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
            >::value
        >::type* = 0>
void process(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
        std::cout << (*iter).first << " " << (*iter).second << "\n";
    }
}
```

A problem arises: when it is indeed a pair that you use. You have two available overloads... The call becomes ambiguous, so you need to add a SFINAE condition on the common implementation:

```
// arbitrary value types
template<typename Iter,
    typename std::enable_if<
        ! is_pair<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>::value
    >::type* = nullptr>
void process(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for (Iter iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << "\n";
    }
}
```

This will ensure that only one implementation is available for a given call as demonstrated on this [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8df0b07e7bc1caa)